# Fbprophet quickstart example - KeyError: 'ds'

Tags: python, facebook, pandas, time-series

Following the quickstart example & having a problem when trying to fit the model at:

```
m.fit(df);
```

The terminal shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cartier/miniconda2/envs/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(key)
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'ds'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prophexample.py", line 10, in <module>
m.fit(df);
File "/home/cartier/miniconda2/envs/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 484, in fit
self.history_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['ds']).sort_values()
File "/home/cartier/miniconda2/envs/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2059, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "/home/cartier/miniconda2/envs/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "/home/cartier/miniconda2/envs/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1386, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "/home/cartier/miniconda2/envs/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3543, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "/home/cartier/miniconda2/envs/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2136, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'ds'
```

When I print the head, tail or entire df it's fine:

```
          ds          y
0  2007-12-10  9.590761
1  2007-12-11  8.519590
2  2007-12-12  8.183677
3  2007-12-13  8.072467
4  2007-12-14  7.893572
```

Is this because I'm not using a notebook or am I missing something else? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the csv file didn't have all the dates. The dates skip from 7/13/08 to 7/31/08. Once I put in the missing dates with some random y values it was fine. Maybe there's a setting/command to ignore missing dates... [image]